# Show more/less option if text exceeds 10 letters

Tags: javascript

I saw this demo http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/show-more-link-shortened-content/ and tried to implement it; how do I set the limit to 10 letters?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.write(str.substring(0, 29) + 
         "<a href='javascript:show('test');'>show/hide</a>");
     document.write("<style type='text/css'>.hidden{display:none}<\/style>");
     function show(area) {
         var obj = document.getElementById(area)
         obj.style.display = (obj.style.display == 'inline') ? 'none' : 'inline'
     }
</script>
<p><strong>This is the result, just test it yourself:</strong></p>

Some text has been hidden. <a href="javascript:show('test');">show/hide</a>
<span class="hidden" id="test">
    Yes, this was hidden.<br>bladiebla bladiebladiebla was also hidden.
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the full demo, there is a jQuery function that has a variable of `var showChar = 100;`.

I presume you would change the variable to however many characters you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have included my solution to the problem below. Rather than look at the amount of characters it takes into consideration the width of the parent and keeps the "preview text" on one line and cuts it off so it doesn't reach outside it's container. The user can click a "more" button to see the full description. This is useful because it can be used in responsive sites where you don't know the ideal amount of characters to show.

http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/3xu9R/

### JS (jQuery or Zepto)

```
function checkLength() {
    this.showing = new Array();
}

checkLength.prototype.check = function() {
    var that = this;
    $('.article').each(function (index) {
        var article = $(this);
        var theP = article.find('p');
        var theMore = article.find('.more');
        if (theP.width() > article.width()) {
            theMore.show();
            that.showing[index] = true;
        } else {
            if (!article.hasClass('active')) {
                theMore.hide();
                that.showing[index] = false;
            } else {
                that.showing[index] = false;
            }
        }
        theMore.text(that.showing[index] ? "More..." : "Less...");
    });
};

$(function () {
    var checker = new checkLength();
    checker.check();
    $('.more').each(function () {

        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).closest('.article').toggleClass('active');
            checker.check();
        });
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        checker.check()
    });
});
```

Edit: Added the show less option. I suppose there are better ways to do it. Probably would have added the "more" and "less" via javascript so it doesn't mess with semantics.